# Display session in html using ng-click after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I am using `express-session` where I am holding products prices. Everything seems works good, but I have problem with display session in html. For example if I have 2 products in session and I add next badge will show `3`, when I refresh page badge is hide, and next add next product badge will show `4`. And if I try display session like `{{ session.cart.totalQty }}` this doesn't work.  `main` is controllerAs, `cart` is function which adding products, counting total price etc and `User.addToCart(...)` is service function returning `$http`.Question is how to display session `totalQty` even if refresh page?

html

```
<sapn class="badge">{{totalQty}}</span>
<a data-target="#" ng-click="main.addCart(price)" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Add to cart</a>
```

controller

```
app.addCart = function(product){
    User.addToCart($routeParams.id).then(function(data){ 
        $scope.totalQty = data.data.cart.totalQty;
    });
}
```

and API

```
router.get('/add-to-cart/:id', function(req, res){
    var cart = new Cart(req.session.cart ? req.session.cart : {});
    Product.findById({ _id : req.params.id }, function(err, product){ 
        if(err) throw err
        if(!product){
            res.json({success:false, message: 'err'});
        } else {

            cart.add(product, product.id);
            req.session.cart = cart;
            res.json({ success:true, product: product, cart:cart });

        }
    })  

});
```

Comment: Do you want to get old badge count after page refresh?

Comment: yes, I would like old badge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to store badge count before you load it from Server.

Something like:

```
User.addToCart($routeParams.id).then(function(data){ 
    $scope.totalQty = data.data.cart.totalQty;
    localStorage.totalQty = $scope.totalQty;
});
```

And when you load your controller just call:

```
$scope.totalQty = localStorage.totalQty || 0;
```

---

I suggest you to check [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) module that will manage `localStorage` by angular way.

Comment: Thank you for help, next lesson behind me

Comment: But now, if I have i.e. 10 badges and clear session and refresh page it shows 10, not 0, next click show 1

Comment: @V.R you just need to reflect session count with your local storage. I don't know your exact project behavior but its really straightforward :)